# Replacing key value from array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array1=Array
(
    [Apr] => stdClass Object
        (
            [months] => 0
            [years] => 0
            [totbooking] => 0
            [nights] => 0
            [revenue] => 0
            [adr] => 0
            [atp] => 0
            [leadtime] => 0
            [alos] => 0
            [share] => 0.60463290145269
        )
   )



$array2=Array
(
    [Apr] => stdClass Object
        (
            [months] => Apr
            [years] => 2016
            [totbooking] => 73
            [nights] => 154
            [revenue] => 26375
            [adr] => 171
            [atp] => 361
            [leadtime] => 24
            [alos] => 2.1096
            [share] => 0
        )
     )
```

I want to replace share . So new array look like

```
    Array
(
    [Apr] => stdClass Object
        (
            [months] => Apr
            [years] => 2016
            [totbooking] => 73
            [nights] => 154
            [revenue] => 26375
            [adr] => 171
            [atp] => 361
            [leadtime] => 24
            [alos] => 2.1096
            [share] => 0.60463290145269
        )
     )
```

Comment: Do it like this `$array2["Apr"]->share = $array1["Apr"]->share;`

Comment: Is this your full code or just an example, is the share variable the only one to change?

Comment: Its just an example. @Sakuto

Comment: @SahilGulati Thanks. Its working

Comment: @RakeshTripathi Welcome ... :)

Comment: So this solution is definitely not universal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will also work for you:

```
 $arr[$newkey] = $arr[$oldkey];
 unset($arr[$oldkey]);
```